# How can I integrate the SwingWorker into the MVC Pattern

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, swingworker

I have a problem with SwingWorker. Currently, I have a model with an time consuming algorithm. I want to show the intermediate result of the algorithm in a specific view. So I have to use SwingWorker, because the GUI must update the value after each loop of the algorithm. The problem is the transfer of the value from the model to the GUI. Where can I insert the SwingWorker class and how can I transfer the data from the model to the view (over the controller), without adding to much "SwingWorker" logic into my model. Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"Where can I insert the SwingWorker class and how can I transfer the data from the model to the view (over the controller), without adding to much "SwingWorker" logic into my model"* and here likes the core of your problem.  The fact is, the `SwingWorker` should be telling the `Controller` that something has updated and the `Controller` will then notify the `View`.  This raises a number of questions.  Who's actually responsible for ensuring the communication between the model and the view (via the controller) is done in the EDT? This leaks implementation details across boundries

Comment: The reason I ask the question is, `SwingWorker` clearly is a UI/view related concept, in MVC, neither the controller or the view should care how the model is implemented.  This would "suggest" that the model should be using the `SwingWorker`, but this, to me, seems inappropriate for the implementation of the mode, which shouldn't care about the UI/view implementation at all.

Comment: So, you need to take a step back.  Have the model do it's thing in some kind of `Thread`, because this is a implementation detail, I'd consider moving it to the model. Notify the controller of changes, which will notify the view, which should then ensure that the results of the notification are carried out inside the EDT

Comment: Having ranted about all that, Swing is a MVC (of types) already. Unless you're "absolutely" required to lay yet another MVC onto of it, I'd consider not trying, while the intention is good, it raises to many issues, produces too much duplicated and boiler plate code and generally makes you question your own existance

Comment: Thank for your answer/time. ;) I've implemented the algorithm with the template method pattern. So in this case i have to add the template method to the implementation of the swingworker and publish the intermediate results, call the controller and update the view. This would deface the code of the model, because there is too much logic in the model, which belongs to the view.

Comment: The only reason to use a `SwingWorker` is produce results which can be updated to the UI, which is clearly not the domain of the model and there is no "clear" answer to the solution, because, as I stated, Swing is already a MVC.  Adding another MVC on top it just complicates the issue.  Instead, your model should generate it's results inside it's own thread and communicate those changes to the controller.  The view should then ensure thread safety on it's end, based on the needs of the UI framework

Comment: So I have to find a way, to start the algorithm after the button is clicked, but in it's own thread. While the algorithm is running, I just call the method controller.setValue, which calls the corresponding method of the view and updates the value of the view, which runs in the EDT. Is this correct? Sounds like I have to implement my own swingworker. :D

Comment: The new thread is the solution of the problem. Now it's working. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You just have to make sure that when the view is notified, it’s checking if the update is occurring within the context of the EDT or not, if not, you need to sync the update to the EDT

Comment: A `SwingWorker` creates/uses its own `Thread`.  There should be no need for creating your own.  The `SwingWorker` can `publish()` intermediate results, which are automatically passed to the EDT for `process(List<T>)` to update to your MVC.  This is all built in scaffolding of the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: I suppose your issue is that the model has a lot of data; you can’t just continue to have the algorithm update the model, since these changes may occur while the EDT is pulling data for display, which could result in inconsistency in the displayed data at best; and exceptions at worst.  If so, the SwingWorker would need to `model.step(); publish(model.clone());` so your MVC gets a consistent entire model update each algorithm step.